# How can I interchangeably use glob.glob("*PDF) and os.listdr("./directory")?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to merge PDF files inside a folder

I tried running the code from the same directory and it worked however when I copied the code to a different location and specified the directory path of PDF files, the merging process is not happening and I keep getting errors.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import glob

x = glob.glob("*pdf")
merger = PdfFileMerger()
 
for pdf in x:
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
 
with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```

This is the code that I wrote when I went one folder up with my source code folder location

```
x = [a for a in os.listdir('./merge_pdf') if a.endswith(".pdf")]
for pdf in x:
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
 
with open("./merge_pdf/result.pdf", "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)

--->FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.pdf'
```

For this reason I am running all of my codes from inside my PDF folders and I know it's not a good practice.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue, I am only in my early learning phase.

I also tried this

```
with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fout:
    merger.write("./merge_pdf/"+fout)
```

Comment: `*.pdf` is a glob that searches in the *current* directory, not in `./merge_pdf`.

Comment: Were you expecting the `listdir` output to include full file paths? It just gives names. You can't open a file by just its name if it's in a different directory.

Comment: "Were you expecting the listdir output to include full file paths" I was but now I know it's not how it works. But still I don't know how to get full file path for saving output file. You seem to know my problem, could you suggest a solution.

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` to combine a directory name with a filename.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob.glob` returns the full path to the file while `os.listdir` only gives the file name. Just stick with glob.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import glob

x = glob.glob("merge_pdf/*pdf")
merger = PdfFileMerger()
 
for pdf in x:
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))
 
with open("merge_pdf/result.pdf", "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```

Another nice option is the `pathlib` module.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = Path("merge_pdf")
result_pdf = dir_path/"result.pdf"

merger = PdfFileMerger()
 
for pdf in dir_path.glob("*pdf"):
    merger.append(pdf.open('rb'))
 
with result_pdf.open("wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```

Comment: This was helpful but still curious, is there any way we could use os.listdir and get this work done? How could I separately specify the the full file path?

Comment: Sure you can use os.listdir... but you are really just reimplementing glob.  The `pathlib` module encapsulates path operations in the `Path` class and is another good option. As for separately specifygin the file path, do you want that as a variable, or perhaps a command line argument, or a prompt?

Comment: I want to try giving path as a variable for this time and after I know how to achieve that I will be flexible giving path in other forms.

Comment: In my second example, I've add the path as a variable, but wrapped in a  `Path`.

Comment: Yes this was really helpful. Thank you